# JasperReports nested loop

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The goal is the following structure

```
Static Text
--------------------
Category 1
    SubCategory 1_1
    SubCategory 1_2
    ...
Category 2
    SubCategory 2_1
    ....
...
--------------------
StaticText
```

To get the dynamic data i use the following bean structure

```
public class  BeanFactory {

  public  static Collection getVehicleData() {return the Collection}
}
```

Category class

```
public class VehicleData {
  private String category;
  private List<WarningData> warnings;
}
```

The WarningData class is a POJO. So can anyone give me a hint how i can get this kind of structure?

1. I tried to use two data set, one is using the beanfactory to create the data and one should use the vehicledata class to get the warningdata. But this did not work for me.
2. I tried to group it. But i don't know how to access the warning data
3. Should i use a table or a list component from the iReport Designer?
4. Can i use a loop in the expression editor?

**Update**
To make this clear. How can i iterate over the subcategories? I succeed with the iteration over the categories, but i don't know how i iterate for every category over the subcategories.

Comment: Are you laying this out in iReport? Why aren't you using iReport's grouping levels?

Comment: @bkb `I tried to use two data set`, `I tried to group it` - you should post th *jrxml* file

Comment: `Can i use a loop in the expression editor?` - What do you mean? Did you read the basic of *JasperReports*? [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) - the good one. And this are [samples](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html)

Comment: @Lisa, at the moment i am trying to create the report with iReport and i don't know about grouping levels. But Thanks i will have a look at it. Alex i thought maybe i can do something like this "$F{warnings}.get(i).getHeadline()" where i is a variable to get the warningdata

Comment: @bkb You can use the subreport, for example. And pass data to it

Comment: Order your query by category, subcategory. In iReport, right-click on the report name in the Report Inspector and select "Add Report Group". Choose the fields to group on.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was in a kind of the hint from Lisa's comment. Instead of the data structure in the question, i created a "flat" structure like the following:

```
public class VehicleData2 {
   private String category;
   private String categoryIconPath;
   private String iconPath;
   private String headline;
   private String warning;
}
```

The last three attributes was encapsuled in a new class WarningData. But I was not able to iterate throw this list of warning data, so in my solution there is e. g. redundancy in the category. But with this kind of structure it is possible to use a report group for the categories and to put the warning data into the detail part of the jasperreport.

Answer (score 0):

The only two ways to *iterate* on subdata of a record seem to be **Subreports** and **Tables**.

Each datasource is an iterator through a flat list. Your report contains only one notion of repetition, that is, repeating a *Detail* section for each record in a datasource. Tables and Subreports both have their own datasources (which may well depend on the current iteration of the containing report), and repeat their *Detail*-sections accordingly. Since they can be nested, jasper theoretically allows arbitrary looping as required. Just that you'll need to introduce a subreport or a table for each loop:

- The *Detail* section of your root record
- The *Detail* section of a **Subreport**
- The *Detail* section of a **Table**